# Loading __typename fields in seperate queries Apollo-Client not Updating UI

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I'm attempting to load information about a type in 2 steps (since the info I'm asking for in  secondQuery will take some time to load):

**Component:**

```
const MyComponent = ({startDate}) => {
  const firstQuery = useQuery(
    GET_INFO_PART_ONE,
    {
     variables: {startDate}
    }
  );

  const secondQuery = useQuery(
    GET_INFO_PART_TWO,
    {
     variables: {startDate}
    }
  );
}
```

**Queries:**

```
export const GET_INFO_PART_ONE = gql`
  query getInfoPartOne(
    $startDate: DateTime!
  ) {
    infoPageResults(
      startDate: $startDate
    ) {
      edges {
        info {
          infoID
          infoFieldOne
          infoFieldTwo
          infoFieldThree
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_INFO_PART_TWO = gql`
  query getInfoPartTwo(
    $startDate: DateTime!
  ) {
    infoPageResults(
      startDate: $startDate
    ) {
      edges {
        info {
          infoID
          infoFieldFour{
            netRate
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

When I do this and both queries resolve, the cache's ROOT_QUERY includes the data as I would expect it, with infoPageResults containing an array of edges where each edge's `info` __typename includes the fields specified in the `GET_INFO_PART_ONE` and `GET_INFO_PART_TWO` queries. I would then expect `firstQuery.data.infoPageResults.edges` in the above component to include the fields loaded from the second query.

**The Problem**

After both firstQuery and secondQuery are finished loading, firstQuery.data.infoPageResults.edges does not contain the fields loaded by secondQuery, even though the cached values look as I would expect them.

1. Is there something obvious I'm misunderstanding about how the query hooks work?
2. Is there a better strategy for loading additional fields onto a _typename in 2 steps?

Answer (score 0):

**Just caches what was queried** ... no node entries cached (additionally, separately - as cache is normalizing cache), because no `id` field (required by default as unique entry id) ... it can be customized to use `infoID` for info type (see docs).

Properly cached node (info) entries can be used to display node details (from 1st query) on 2nd query result rendering list ... using additional 'cache-only' policy queries (info node by id) in subcomponents (react).

**Start with more standard example/tutorial to explore possibilities.**

---

**update**

No, **data fetched separately are accessible separately** ... it's not cache problem and not querying problem...

- 1st query won't return fields/properties fetched in 2nd query ... by design;
- list rendered using 1st result won't be refreshed when 2nd query result will arrive ... if doesn't contain ref/not consume 2nd data;

**You can use/pass both data in parallel or combine them (in immutable way) before passing to some view component** ('Presentational and Container Component Pattern') ... **list can be rendered using one prop and updated when 2nd prop changes**.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm not exactly sure what you're suggesting here. The `InMemoryCache` of the client is configured to use `infoID` rather than the default `id` field via the `dataIdFromObject` config option. If I want all details (loaded from 1st and 2nd queries) of all `info` pageResults are you suggesting I add a 3rd query with a cache-only policy?

Comment: ... you should mention about all non-standard config/usage ... and describe how you're passing or render this data ... and what is not updated ...

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for this answer. Sounds like it's a  core misunderstanding on my part about how the query hooks work.